# how to redirect to particular url on 404

Tags: python, bottle

```
@error(404)
def error404(error):
    return 'Nothing here, sorry'
```

This is the way to response 404 in `bottle framework`. But On 404 I want to redirect to particular url say http://abc.com/. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

```
@error(404)
def error404(error):
    from bottle import redirect
    # maybe test the error to see where you want to go next?
    redirect(new_url, 303) # HTTP 303 should be used in this case
```

**EDIT** I'm not 100% sure this can be done, and I can't test it right now, but I'll test it later and update the answer unless you beat me to it.

Comment: What version of bottle are you using? I am having trouble with error handling in bottle - I think because the docs are not up to date with the code. I tried the redirect code above using bottle 0.9.dev and got a 500 response code and the display "Critical Error" Error:
HTTPResponse('HTTP Response 303',)

Comment: Sorry for delay, was off StackOverflow for a while. The example refers to the HEAD version from Git. It might have changed meanwhile, but I doubt it. Have you checked what the exact error occurred in your app? 500 usually suggest errors in your code.

Answer (score 3):

```
    @app.error(404)
    def error(err):
        bottle.response.status = 303 
        bottle.response.header['Location'] = '/'
```

Comment: Can you explain why it works rather than just giving then answer?

Answer (score -3):

```
import urllib
url = urllib.urlopen('www.google.com/testing') #a 404 address
if url.code == 404:
    url = urllib.urlopen('www.google.com')
```

When a urlobject is created the .code instance returns the code of the page,